# Token holders not showing on mainnet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, bscscan

I got a problem which i can’t understand the reason.
Made a erc20 token, and deployed on testnet
Here everything goes fine and work as expected,
But when i deployed it on mainnet, the block explorer shows holders are 0
Also holders tab is empty.
And in addition, tokens are displaying on metamask, but not visible in token holder wallet on block explorer.

Is there anybody who knows the problem??
It very weird for me.
Cause it’s okay on testnet but not on mainnet!

I searched for it on google, but there is just few results about the problme, and those are just saying about Transfer event and emitting it for minting the token.
This is not my case, cause i have all the events and checked them hundred times.

I cross my fingers hoping someone helps me getting this solved

Comment: have a link to the token?

Comment: Here is the link: https://bscscan.com/token/0x7a270cce119cf60131b0b77acfc6de60aaa245bd

Comment: Etherscan/Bscscan are closed source third party block explorer. We don't know how they handle contracts and tokens. In the past verifying the contract and performing at least one transfer will identify the contract as a token. I'll suggest to contact their customer support.

Comment: as bscscan placed a notification bar on their website, it seems there is an issue on new token balances on Binance smart chain explorer which they are trying to resolve. I checked some other new tokens, and they have the same situation...many transactions but 0 holders.

Answer (score 0):

All block explorers are "eventually consistent", meaning the data might not be real time or up to date all of the time, but it eventually will be.

Most block explorers use `Transfer` events from the ERC20 specification to figure out how many holders there are and so on, but since this is likely a low priority job, especially for largely unknown tokens, it might not be visible instantly.

This largely depends on the block explorer, though. If you used Etherscan on testnet, and you use Etherscan on mainnet, it *will* show up eventually, if it is the same contract, and it worked on testnet.

Comment: The token holders are okay in testnets(bsc and eth)…but on mainnet, it is showing 0 holders! It’s an strange happening to me